# salesforce field mapping

Tags: custom-field, fieldsets, architecture

I have a table (Detail) in SQL and creating a custom object in Salesforce (Detail__c).

Below are the fields in SQL Detail Table:

[image]

Will they be a picklist? But how can I relate Detail_Acc_no, Description, Type and Detail_account_class all in one picklist? How can this be structured?

Comment: Generally you don't merge several fields into a single picklist. Are any of these fields picklists themselves? Do you have a reason for trying to concatenate these fields into a single field? Why don't you just create mirrored fields and copy the values over from your SQL table?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't want to merge several fields into a single picklist. What are mirrored fields? I'm try to fit the SQL structure into Salesforce in a best possible way.

Comment: You create a field on your custom object in salesforce with the same schema definition, and when merging your data, copy your SQL data into that field. Behind the UI, salesforce is basically just a bunch of SQL tables anyway, you just need to set up the fields so they can easily pass data between the two via your integration code.

Comment: I've never done this trailhead, but it seems relevant to what your doing: [Integrate External Data](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_connect/units/lightning_connect_integrate), I'd recomend giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This can be truly a design decision as whether you could identify a field as an attribute or as a separate object.

If you want to identify a field to be picklist then it will hold only the description part. Though in back end SOQL server it can maintained with ID and Description.

If you to identify that thing as an object then probably you need to create object and could relate them to the main object via. lookup or Master-Detail relationship.

This object can hold several other attributes along with ID (External) and Description.